# How to upload multiple base64 encoded images in php

Tags: php, jquery

```js
$('.image-editor').each(function(){
  $(this).cropit();
});
$('.export').click(function(){
  var category = [];
  $("input[name='category']:checked").each(function(){
    category.push(this.value);
 });
  var imageData = [];
  $('.image-editor').each(function(){
      imageData.push( $(this).cropit() );
  });
  $.ajax({
      url: "upload.php",
      type: "POST",
      data: {
      imageData: imageData,
      category: category
    },
      success: function (result){
        alert(result);
    }
  });
});
```

```css
.col100{
  width:100%;
}
.left{
  float:left;
}
.mbottom10{
  margin-bottom:20x;
}
.clearfix:after {
   content: " "; /* Older browser do not support empty content */
   visibility: hidden;
   display: block;
   height: 0;
   clear: both;
}

.image-editor{
 width: 100%;
 float:left;
}
.cropit-preview {
  float:left;
  background-color: #f8f8f8;
  background-size: cover;
  width: 200px;
  height: 150px;
}
.cropit-preview-image-container {
  cursor: move;
}
.image-size-label {
  margin-top: 10px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/cropit/0.5.1/jquery.cropit.min.js"></script>
<html>
<head>
</head>
<body>
  <section class="col100 left mbottom10">
    <input type="checkbox" name="category" value="1"> Slide
    <input type="checkbox" name="category" value="2" id="gallery"> Gallery
    <input type="submit" name="submit" class="export" />
 </section>
  <div class="clearfix"></div><br/>
  <article class="image-editor">
    <input type="file" class="cropit-image-input" /><br/>
    <input type="range" class="cropit-image-zoom-input" /><br/>
    <section class="cropit-preview"></section><br/>
   </article>
   <div class="clearfix"></div><br/>
  <article class="image-editor">
    <input type="file" class="cropit-image-input" /><br/>
    <input type="range" class="cropit-image-zoom-input" /><br/>
    <section class="cropit-preview"></section><br/>
   </article>
</body>
</html>
```

I am trying to upload multiple `base64 encoded image` to server, but it is uploading only first one. After passing multiple image forming array through ajax with the help of `@ZakariaAcharki`, I've tried `foreach loop` in php. But, only one and first image is uploading and submitting !, Is following process and code is wrong according to ajax data provided in fiddle ?

```
foreach ($_POST["imageData"] AS $key => $category){
    $img = substr(explode(";",$category)[1], 7);
    $imgnm = time().'.jpg';
    $folder = '../images/slide/'.$imgnm;
    file_put_contents($folder, base64_decode($img));
}
```

Comment: Provide a [mcve]

Comment: "doesn't work" means what? You get a console error? Or some unexpected behaviour? Please clarify what you expected to happen and what actually happens.

Comment: Your last example will work you just need to define `imageData`: `var imageData = $(this).cropit();`

Comment: _how to store each value in array in jquery_ value of what ?

Comment: @LGSon Please see my updated question..and fiddle

Comment: @ADyson Please see updated question and fiddle

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan, it works but it send only one and first image, Please see my updated question and fiddle..

Comment: your update doesn't answer any of the questions I asked, though

Comment: @ADyson, It was my weakness that I couldn't explain clearly, Please see updated heading and question, now it should be clear, Thanks

Comment: Ok thanks. So have you looked in your browser's developer tools, in the network tab, to see what is actually being sent in the AJAX request? Is there data in there according to what you expected? Then in PHP what is the content of $_POST (you can use var_dump($_POST); to see it)? Again does it match your expectations? Does the PHP you've written query that structure correctly? In other words we're trying to see if the problem is client-side or server-side. If you're unsure, show us the result of these investigations using some sample data.

Answer (score 1):

**[Working fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/z_acharki/bshg793v/2/)**.

> Is it possible to store each value of same CSS class in an array?

Yes, this is possible try to add it directly to the array, like :

```
var imageData = [];

$('.image-editor').each(function(){
    imageData.push( $(this).cropit('export') );
});
```

Comment: Welcome, what you expect from the array to hold at the end of process?

Comment: It was my weakness that I couldn't explain clearly, Please see updated heading and question, now it should be clear, thanks

Comment: Try it now with  `export` option , this is an example https://jsfiddle.net/z_acharki/bshg793v/2/